# Custom field type in Sitecore 8. After completing the command successfully, I'd like to enable the save button

Tags: content-editor, commands

I have a custom field type in Sitecore 8.

I use the `Context.ClientPage.SendMessage` to call the `contenteditor:save` command.
This works, but forces the page to reload producing a warning dialogue to pop up.
I actually only want the Save button to be enabled, so just need the page to know the state has changed.

This is my current code:

```csharp
protected void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");

    if (args.IsPostBack)
    {
        Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, "contenteditor:save");
        return;
    }

    var urlString = new UrlString(args.Parameters["url"]);
    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.ShowModalDialog(urlString.ToString(), "700", "510", "", true);
    args.WaitForPostBack();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```cs
Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Modified = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

To notify the Sitecore Client about changes in a custom field you have to call/override SetModified:

```csharp
protected override void SetModified()
{
    base.SetModified();
    if (base.TrackModified)
    {
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Modified = true;
    }
}
```